# Automatically create checkbox in new line

Tags: org-mode, list

When creating a list in org-mode, one can press M-RET to create a new line which already has a list item of the same indentation as the line above it in it.

How can one achieve the same thing but with a checkbox added if (and only if) the line one presses M-RET in has a checkbox?

Comment: On Org 9, same way. No need for even `M`. Just write `+ [ ] foo RET` and you'll get a new `+ [ ]`.

Comment: What about S-M-RET? (shift + alt + return)

Comment: @FrancescoTurco Ah, thanks. I didn't know of this combination. Is it possible to do the same thing with M-RET, though? I don't like the S-M combinations because pressing shift and meta at the same time is hard.

Comment: @UTF-8: I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: @mankoff No, it not working, it works just like RET, no extra character.